# Coin toss game expectation

Tags: probability, markov-chains

Person $A$ and $B$ are going to play a coin toss game. There is an initial score $0$, and whenever a head/tail appears, the score $+1$/$-1$. Repeat the coin toss until one wins, that is, when the score reaches $+2$/$-2$, $A$/$B$ wins the game. There is also an initial stake \$$1$ for the game and person $A$ has the option to double the stake every time before a coin toss. When one person wins the game, the other player needs to pay the amount of dollars on the stake to the winner. The question is: if you are person $A$, what is your strategy and what is your highest expected payoff of the game?

I suspect that the stake should be doubled when you have a score of $0$ or $+1$ but if that is the case, the expectation will be infinity according to my calculation. Also, I ran a computer simulation on $10$ runs of $1000000$ games, but for the $10$ means I get, the mean does not converge to a single value. Could someone enlighten me what is the correct approach?

Comment: Please explain the game again, what is the "stake" and how ist it related to the wins of the one or the other player. So far, i can model the whole using the five states `(-2)---(-1)---(0)---(+1)---(+2)` (from A's perspective) where the states $\pm2$ are final, and we start in zero. Assume we have a path of the shape $0,1,0,1,0,-1,0,-1,0,1,0,1,0,1,2$, and $A$ wins. What is the payoff?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x$ denote player $A$'s score before a toss.

There are two strategies to consider . . .

- Player $A$ doubles only at $x=1$.$\\[4pt]$

  Player $A$ doubles at both $x=0\;$and $x=1$.

First suppose player $A$ doubles only at $x=1$.

Let $W_k$ be the probability that player $A$ wins exactly $2^k$, and let $L_k$ be the probability that player $A$ loses exactly $2^k$.

Starting at $x=0$, let $p$ be the probability of reaching $x=1$ before reaching $x=-2$.

It's easily shown that $p={\large{\frac{2}{3}}}$.

There's no way for $A$ to win exactly $1$, hence $W_0=0$.

For $A$ to lose exactly $1$, the score, starting at $x=0$, must reach $x=-2$ before reaching $x=1$, hence $L_0=1-p={\large{\frac{1}{3}}}$.

For $A$ to win exactly $2$, the score, starting at $x=0$, must reach $x=1$ before reaching $x=-2$, and once reaching $x=1$, the next toss must be $\text{H},\;$hence 
$W_1=(p)\bigl({\large{\frac{1}{2}}}\bigr)=\bigl({\large{\frac{2}{3}}}\bigr)\bigl({\large{\frac{1}{2}}}\bigr)={\large{\frac{1}{3}}}$.

Considering the $2$-toss sequences $\text{TH},\text{HT},\;$we get the recursion
$$
\begin{cases}
W_k=\frac{1}{4}W_k+\frac{1}{4}W_{k-1}&\text{for}\;k\ge 2\\[4pt]
L_k=\frac{1}{4}L_k+\frac{1}{4}L_{k-1}&\text{for}\;k\ge 1\\
\end{cases}
$$
or equivalently,
$$
\begin{cases}
W_k=\frac{1}{3}W_{k-1}&\text{for}\;k\ge 2\\[4pt]
L_k=\frac{1}{3}L_{k-1}&\text{for}\;k\ge 1\\
\end{cases}
$$
It follows that
$$
\begin{cases}
W_0=0\\[4pt]
W_k=\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^k&\text{if}\;k\ge 1\\[4pt]
L_k=\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{k+1}&\text{if}\;k\ge 0\\
\end{cases}
$$
Letting $e$ denote $A$'s expectation using this strategy, we get
\begin{align*}
e&=
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(W_k\right)\left(2^k\right)
-
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(L_k\right)\left(2^k\right)\\[4pt]
&=
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left({\small{\frac{2}{3}}}\right)^k
-
\left({\small{\frac{1}{3}}}\right)\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left({\small{\frac{2}{3}}}\right)^k\\[4pt]
&=2-1\\[4pt]
&=1
\end{align*}
Next, suppose player $A$ doubles at both $x=0$ and $x=1$.

Using this strategy, let $e$ be player $A$'s expectation.

For sequences of $2n$ tosses where the game ends on toss $2n$, there is a one-to-one correspondence between sequences where $A$ loses, and sequences where $A$ wins, obtained by using the exact same toss sequence except reversing the last two tosses from $\text{TT}$ to $\text{HH}$. Call such sequences conjugates of each other. But for any pair of conjugate sequences, if the losing one loses $2^k$, the winning one wins $2^{k+1}$, hence the conditional expectation, given that the game ends after $2n$ tosses, is positive.

It follows that $e > 0$ (possibly positive infinity).

Suppose $e$ is finite.

Starting at $x=0$, and considering the $2$-toss sequences $\text{TT},\text{TH},\text{HT},\text{HH}$, we get the recursion
$$e=\left(\small{\frac{1}{4}}\right)(-2)+\left(\small{\frac{1}{4}}\right)(2e)+\left(\small{\frac{1}{4}}\right)(4e)+\left(\small{\frac{1}{4}}\right)(4)$$
which yields $e=-1$, contrary to $e > 0$.

It follows that $e=+\infty$.

Thus, if the goal is to maximize expectation, then doubling at both $x=0$ and $x=1$ is optimal.

But the conjugate of a big win is a big loss (though only half as much), so this strategy, though it has expectation positive infinity, and offers the potential for huge gains, also risks huge losses.

Comment: I would love to ask how does the recursive formula for the first strategy originates from? I suppose the $\frac{1}{4} W_{k-1}$ is from the TH sequence when we are at +1 state, but shouldn't that be $\frac{1}{2} W_k$ for "HT" sequence as we will only need a Head to come up to make it $W_k$, regardless of the latter toss being H or T.

Comment: @dust: My post is from $2$ years ago, so I'll need some time to review it. I won't have time to look at it today, but I'll fool with it either tomorrow or the day after tomorrow.

Comment: no worries, thanks a lot for helping even if this is from quite a while ago.

Comment: @dust: Assume strategy $1$ (player $A$ doubles only at $x=1$) and let $k\ge 2$. Starting at $x=0$, to win exactly $2^k$, there are two cases:$\;$Case $(1)$:$\;$An initial $2$-term toss sequence of $\text{TH}$ followed by a sequence which, if the game were to start over, would win exactly $2^k$.$\;$Case $(2)$:$\;$An initial $2$-term toss sequence of $\text{HT}$ followed by a sequence which, if the game were to start over, would win exactly $2^{k-1}$.

Comment: @dust: Thus, case $(1)$ occurs with probability ${\large{\frac{1}{4}}}W_k$ and case $(2)$ occurs with probability ${\large{\frac{1}{4}}}W_{k-1}$, hence, for $k\ge 2$, we get $W_k={\large{\frac{1}{4}}}W_k+{\large{\frac{1}{4}}}W_{k-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

For the case in which you only double at $x=1$, a recursive approach can be used to find the expected value too.
Using each two-toss sequence TT, TH, HT, and HH we get the following equation:

$e = \frac{1}{4}*-1 + \frac{1}{4}*e + \frac{1}{4}*2e + \frac{1}{4}*2 $.

Solving yields e = 1.